# Can the ramanujan summation formula be used to evaluate convergent series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series, ramanujan-summation

I know it's used to give values to divergent series, but when applied to absolutely convergent series, does it give the value at which the series converges?

By the way since someone asked about how I define the Ramanujan summation formula here it is:
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)=-\frac{f(0)}{2}+i \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(i t)-f(-i t)}{e^{2π t}-1} d t$

Comment: **Absolutely** convergent ? How did you define the Ramanujan summation

Comment: How did you define $f$ ? Many analytic functions take the same values at the integers.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I kinda think it must be continuous at least from 0 to infinity

Comment: Rephrasing explanations in Konrad Knopp's monography on series (and summations): *"if a summation method would not give the correct value for a convergent series it would be dismissed"* - so, sloppily - one might say: such a method would not be found in any math-book for the study of summation procedures...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Ramanujan summation basically is the indefnite sum, $\sum_{n}f(n)=F(n)$ with the indefinite sum being true in the neighbourhood of f(n) which makes the solution unique, and $\sum_{n=a}^{b}f(n)=F(b)-F(a-1)$ We define the ramanujan sum value as a=1 so that $\sum_{n=a}^{b}f(n)=F(b)-F(0)$, if a sum is convergent then F(b) goes to infinity, and is 0. If the sum is divergent, then F(b) diverges and will be "disregarded", the constant associate value with the sum is then -F(0). Because F(0) is often ill defined, we can write it as, $-F(0)=-F(1)+f(1)$.

It would be super pointless as summation methode if this wasn't true. People make this topic so much harder then it needs to be.

Comment: So, if I wanted to find the value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ I could use this formula?

Comment: If it works for divergent series it also works for convergent series. But don't use it, you don't know it's meaning, where it's from and whats limitations. You are skipping content, and that's like cheating, it's fun for a little while but also depletes meaning and ruined long term fun. Let it intrigue you but stay away from using it.

Comment: Such a great recommendation, thanks!

Comment: In any case, do you know where could I learn about this? Seems so interesting

Comment: Learn about sums in general. Start with convergent sums, and definite sums. It's rather easy to compute.

Comment: @Perch - I've learnt much from the book of Konrad Knopp on "Series", with its special chapter ( No. 13, if I recall correctly) about divergent series. The original edition (in german) is extremely readable, many examples & exercises, and I think there is an english translation which is also online available.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it